# Access filtered material-table data so standard filters play nicely with my custom filters

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I have a material-table table with a lot of filters, some of which are custom. Checkboxes only for right now but more are coming later.

The problem is that I can't access their filtered data, only the original data I sent to the table to start before any filtering happens at all. So if I use my own custom filters, it erases any of the existing filters a user added. The standard filters and my filters can't work together because they're not using the same data.

Here's a simple example of the problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-lovelace-0o70j?file=/src/App.js

I could of course remove all of their filters and create all of my own, but that seems silly since they have done a great job with their filters and I like their functionality.

My thinking is that if I can get access to the filtered data, I could just use that going forward.

Or is there a better way to do this that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Why do you need a custom filter for checkbox?

Comment: @MindaugasNakrosis

Check out this working solution of what I was trying to do

https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-field-741ji?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working solution that was provided by Domino987 on the Material-Table Gitter forum.

https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-field-741ji?file=/src/App.js

Incredible place to get help and Domino is super helpful, I can't say enough about how much he provides!